# How to change the direction (angle) of bullet after collision in the direction of motion in corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to change the bullet angle after collision, it should change the direction in which it is moving after collision, and must stop rotating after collision.... please give any suggestions... thanks

Sample code is written below

```
local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()

local obj

physics.setScale( 60 ) 
physics.setGravity( 0, 0 ) 

display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )
local obstacle = display.newCircle( 250, 250, 60 )
obstacle.x = display.contentWidth/2; obstacle.y = 200
physics.addBody( obstacle, { density=150, friction=0.2, bounce=0} )
obstacle.isBullet=true


obj = display.newRect(0, 0,20,40)
obj.x = display.contentWidth/2; obj.y = 780
obj.isBullet = true 
obj.color = "white"
physics.addBody( obj, { density=1, friction=0.4, bounce=0.1} )

local target = display.newCircle( 250, 250, 60 )
target.x = obj.x; target.y = obj.y; target.alpha = 0


local function Shot( event )
    local t = event.target

    local phase = event.phase
    if "began" == phase then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t )
        t.isFocus = true

        t:setLinearVelocity( 0, 0 )
        t.angularVelocity = 0

        target.x = t.x
        target.y = t.y

        startRotation = function()
            target.rotation = target.rotation + 4
        end

        Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", startRotation )

        local showTarget = transition.to( target, { alpha=0.4, xScale=0.4, yScale=0.4, time=200 } )
        myLine = nil

    elseif t.isFocus then
        if "moved" == phase then

    if ( myLine ) then
                myLine.parent:remove( myLine ) -- erase previous line, if any
            end
            myLine = display.newLine( t.x,t.y, event.x,event.y )
            myLine:setColor( 255, 255, 255, 50 )
            myLine.width = 8

        elseif "ended" == phase or "cancelled" == phase then

            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
            t.isFocus = false

            local stopRotation = function()
                Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", startRotation )
            end

            local hideTarget = transition.to( target, { alpha=0, xScale=1.0, yScale=1.0, time=200, onComplete=stopRotation } )

            if ( myLine ) then
                myLine.parent:remove( myLine )
            end

            t:applyForce( (t.x - event.x), (t.y - event.y), t.x, t.y )

        end
    end

return true
end

obj:addEventListener( "touch", Shot)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
local physics = require "physics"
physics.start()

local rect1 = display.newRect(480,0,10,320)
physics.addBody(rect1, "static")

local rect2 = display.newRect(20,100,20,20)

local function shot()
    physics.addBody(rect2, "dynamic")
    rect2:applyForce( 1000, 0, rect2.x, rect2.y )
    rect2.myName = "rect2"
end
rect2:addEventListener("touch", shot)
```